# IF EXIST returns false for existing file when batch executed by TeamCity agent

Tags: windows, command-line, teamcity

In `npm.cmd` file there is next lines:

```
ECHO %NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS%

IF EXIST "%NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS%" (
  ECHO FILE EXISTS
  SET "NPM_CLI_JS=%NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS%"
)

"%NODE_EXE%" "%NPM_CLI_JS%" %*
```

When this is executed `ECHO` prints: `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js`. I have checked the file - it exists. When I run my self the batch as SYSTEM user - it also works. But when `npm` command is executed by TeamCity agent, it thinks, that the `npm-cli.js` file does not exist.

I have checked access right to the file and the folder, and everything is fine. Even more, when I remove `IF` and leave only `SET` command node can find, end execute the file.

For testing I've wrote a script that checks if all the folders exist. Run it from TeamCity test shows, that it thinks folders up to `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming` do exist, but everything after do not exist.

Executing `DIR /A` command from TeamCity command line step, printed:

```
03/02/2017  10:31 AM    <DIR>          .
03/02/2017  10:31 AM    <DIR>          ..
10/26/2015  01:33 PM    <DIR>          Microsoft
03/02/2017  10:31 AM    <DIR>          NuGet
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  122,662,453,248 bytes free
```

While in reality there is 3 folder not shown in result.

What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Does the variable have the right value?

Comment: Yes. Value is right.

Comment: After a bit more of testing, it appears that this happens only when command is executed by TeamCity agent. Running the `batch` file from `SYSTEM` user do not have this behavior.

Comment: So is it a path/current directory issue?

Comment: @shawnt00 I think it is some issue with this particular path. I also updated the questions to include more details that I have found so far.